# Can I make just one route to get any info about my model object passing strings or json objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to make a single route that returns any info about my model considering the params that I'm passing to it.

For example: If I access the url, passing a string called "name" and "id", it should return the "name" of the object, if I pass "email" and "id", it should return the "email" of the object.

Something like that:

```
get "person/" => "persons/any_info_about" # host/persons?name"
```

Is there a way using only one route to get any info based on my params?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't pass arbitrary parameter names to the endpoint like

```
GET /person/12345?name,email,foo,bar
```

because then it would be difficult to know what parameter to check. Instead, expect something like

```
GET /person/12345?fields=name,email,foo,bar
```

(param name is `"fields"`, param value is `"name,email,foo,bar"`).

Then in controller:

```
def show
  fields = params[:fields].try { |value| value.split(',') }
  @person = ...
  @data = @person.attributes.slice(*fields)
end
```

Comment: thank you for helping, I used your way to split the string than I convertted they to symbols to create a jbuilder to render!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Don't mention the specific parameter names in the route. Just specify the model and action name:

```
get "person" => "person#everything"
```

And take care of the parameters in the action method:

```
model PersonsController < ApplicationController
  def everything
    if params[:id] && params[:name]
      ...
    end
    if params[:id] && params[:email]
      ...
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: It really helped, but instead of the conditional methods I mapped the params, thanks!!